# mongodb update doesn't update immediately

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I am trying to add an User object to my Game object's field "players_list", which is a list of User objects. This is what my Game object looks like:

```js
{ players_list:
   [ { games: [Array],
       _id: '5b0e112ff13033792f08566f',
       email: 'c',
       password: '$2a$10$iWOBvVf4KAPwbH7zDczfYeI5iXI721jQ7bN1juJ4Us3R.Lqetmhfu',
       handle: 'C',
       __v: 0,
       id: '5b0e112ff13033792f08566f' } ],
  _id: '5b0e181aeb766e7bfaf2fb09',
  players_status:
   [ { _id: '5b0e181aeb766e7bfaf2fb0a',
       playerId: '5b0e112ff13033792f08566f',
       status: 'Joined' } ],
  postGameEvaluation: [],
  date: 'QQQQ',
  time: 'QQQQ',
  duration: 4,
  players_needed: 4,
  max_players: 4,
  level: 4,
  author:
   { games:
      [ '5b0e13e69d35007a147578da',
        '5b0e15b4b117987b00d68cb4',
        '5b0e181aeb766e7bfaf2fb09' ],
     _id: '5b0e112ff13033792f08566f',
     email: 'c',
     password: '$2a$10$iWOBvVf4KAPwbH7zDczfYeI5iXI721jQ7bN1juJ4Us3R.Lqetmhfu',
     handle: 'C',
     __v: 0,
     id: '5b0e112ff13033792f08566f' },
  __v: 0 }
```

and this is what my User objet looks like

```html
{ games: [],
  _id: 5b0e1820eb766e7bfaf2fb0b,
  email: 'f',
  password: '$2a$10$JmS.9axW8batMUKzE7OQx.GShdNDt09eArXfYGoI/DUWEKVwAn5ju',
  handle: 'F',
  __v: 0 }
```

I then run `req.body.players_list.push(req.user)` to add the User object to the player_list field of the Game object. This is what by req.body looks like after adding the User object:

```js
{ players_list:
   [ { games: [Array],
       _id: '5b0e112ff13033792f08566f',
       email: 'c',
       password: '$2a$10$iWOBvVf4KAPwbH7zDczfYeI5iXI721jQ7bN1juJ4Us3R.Lqetmhfu',
       handle: 'C',
       __v: 0,
       id: '5b0e112ff13033792f08566f' },
     { games: [],
       _id: 5b0e1820eb766e7bfaf2fb0b,
       email: 'f',
       password: '$2a$10$JmS.9axW8batMUKzE7OQx.GShdNDt09eArXfYGoI/DUWEKVwAn5ju',
       handle: 'F',
       __v: 0 } ],
  _id: '5b0e181aeb766e7bfaf2fb09',
  players_status:
   [ { _id: '5b0e181aeb766e7bfaf2fb0a',
       playerId: '5b0e112ff13033792f08566f',
       status: 'Joined' } ],
  postGameEvaluation: [],
  date: 'QQQQ',
  time: 'QQQQ',
  duration: 4,
  players_needed: 4,
  max_players: 4,
  level: 4,
  author:
   { games:
      [ '5b0e13e69d35007a147578da',
        '5b0e15b4b117987b00d68cb4',
        '5b0e181aeb766e7bfaf2fb09' ],
     _id: '5b0e112ff13033792f08566f',
     email: 'c',
     password: '$2a$10$iWOBvVf4KAPwbH7zDczfYeI5iXI721jQ7bN1juJ4Us3R.Lqetmhfu',
     handle: 'C',
     __v: 0,
     id: '5b0e112ff13033792f08566f' },
  __v: 0 }
```

So, I then update the Game object in mongo with `Post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body).then((result) => {...`, but the result doesn't contain the new User. This is what my result looks like

```js
{ players_list: [ 5b0e112ff13033792f08566f ],
  _id: 5b0e181aeb766e7bfaf2fb09,
  players_status:
   [ { _id: 5b0e181aeb766e7bfaf2fb0a,
       playerId: '5b0e112ff13033792f08566f',
       status: 'Joined' } ],
  postGameEvaluation: [],
  date: 'QQQQ',
  time: 'QQQQ',
  duration: 4,
  players_needed: 4,
  max_players: 4,
  level: 4,
  author: 5b0e112ff13033792f08566f,
  __v: 0 }
```

The strange thing is that if I leave my current React Component, and then go back into it (thus triggering fetchUser and fetchGame), then the Game fetched does have the new User in its players_list. Does this happen because the mongo update function is asynchronous? Even so, I thought that the `.then((result) => {` in `Post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body).then((result) => {` made sure that `Post.findByIdAndUpdate` completed first before continuing

Comment: Use `findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body).exec().then(...` to get a promise and not the mongoose query thing. (which has a `.then` but is not a real  promise.) Relevant [queries-are-not-promises](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises) and also the [findByIdAndUpdate docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyidandupdate_findByIdAndUpdate) which shows that it returns a query object.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the docs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyidandupdate_findByIdAndUpdate  you'll notice that findByIdAndUpdate returns the original object, not the updated doc.  You have to pass in `{new: true}` as options for it to resolve with the updated object.